# Sticky headers like android contacts using react-native

Tags: react-native

How can I make the section list header stick on the left side like the android contacts app using react-native section list [image]

Comment: Your requirement is not clear

Comment: The sticky header in SectionList of react-native sticks on top of the rows. I want the sticky header on the left adjacent to the row like the android contacts app. The header should move adjacent to the first row of the section and then stick till a next header replaces it. The  header should not be above the row rather on the same level to the left.